# Rails Minitest ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method for nil:NilClas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

Been trying to debug this for two days and I'm just stuck. I have a view that I'm trying to test in rails and the view works perfectly when I test manually in the browser but I keep getting this error in my controller test:

`ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method "name" for nil:NilClass` [Here is the full error message](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/f6f494499a0eb6502b238d52fd358a1b).

Here's the test (test/controllers/quotes_controller_test.rb):

```
  test "should get quotes index as browse" do
    get browse_path
    assert_response :success
  end
```

It's breaking where I render this partial (views/quotes/browse.html.erb):

```
  <% if @recent_quotes.any? %>
    <aside class="recent-quotes browse-quotes col-7">
      <%= render @recent_quotes %>
    </aside>
  <% end %>
```

The partial looks like this (views/quotes/_quote.html.erb):

```
<blockquote id="quote<%= quote.id %> blockquote">
  <small class="text-muted">
    <%= link_to quote.topic.name, artist_path(quote.topic) %>
  </small>
  <p class="mb-0"><%= link_to quote.content, quote_path(quote) %></p>

  <footer class="blockquote-footer">
      <cite title="Source">
        <%= link_to quote.speaker.name, quote.source %>
      </cite>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```

And the controller action looks like this (controllers/quotes_controller.rb):

```
  def browse
    @artists = Artist.all
    @recent_quotes  = Quote.all.limit(7)
  end
```

Again, everything works great in the browser, but I can't get that simple test to pass. If I remove the partial it passes, so the route is working fine. I think that the test is just looking for the `name` method in the first call to `quote.topic.name` and not finding it.

But it's working in the browser, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this test.

Comment: The `name` method is an attribute on the associated Artist model. My Quote model belongs_to :speaker, class_name: "Artist" and belongs_to :topic,   class_name: "Artist", and my Artist model has_many :spoken_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :speaker_id
  has_many :topic_quotes,  class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :topic_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't enough reputation for comments, so I'll try to answer.

What is in your fixtures? Did you define a topic-artist (with name) for all `recent_quotes`?

Fixtures bypasses all validations, so even if you have it on the Quote class, you'll not get any errors for invalid fixture

In the controller you have `@recent_quotes  = Quote.all.limit(7)`.
But in the fixtures you define the speaker and topic only for 5 quotes.
This part:

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
quote_<%= n %>:
  user: jordan
  content: <%= Faker::Lorem.unique.sentence %>
  speaker_id: <%= rand(1..5) %>
  topic_id: <%= rand(6..10) %>
  created_at: <%= 42.days.ago %>
<% end %>
```

doesn't work, because you have no artists with ids in `1..10`. IDs are not set starting from 1 every time when fixtures creates instances, you artists have IDs like `503576764`. So this part really creates quotes, but their `topic.name` is nil, because the topic does not exist.

You need to specify speaker&topic manually for 7 fixtures at least. Or you need to remove the part with `30.times` - I'm not sure that you really need it. Common practice is to use 2-3 instances in fixtures.You can read more about fixtures [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)

Or you can change fixtures to [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails), it will give you more explicit and convenient work with test records.

And one more thing. In such situations there is a very simple debugging tool. Just add some lines to your controller:

```
 def browse
    @artists = Artist.all
    @recent_quotes  = Quote.all.limit(7)
    @recent_quotes.map do |quote| 
      # you can add all what you need in this array
      p [quote.valid?, quote.errors, quote.speaker, quote.topic] 
    end
 end
```

and run tests. You'll see all info in the test output.

Comment: Fixtures are here: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/45a6609b4415769955bd566aa213501b I'm setting a topic_id and speaker_id in the fixtures, but maybe I'm doing that wrong? I think you may be onto something because the user profile (where it shows all the user's quotes they have created works in the browser, but it's the same error in my tests). So what would be a better way of making these fixtures? Here's my db schema if that helps https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/0600d32fe1d1eba6d395dc2fa999d782.

Comment: Updated my Quotes.yml fixture to this https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/dc2446fcecf65703c36aaf2ab00b88b6 but still doesn't fix the test

Comment: Also dropped into the test console and it appears that those fixtures are now creating the right association https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/695508b677f5dd455afeba8eb6603105

Comment: Thanks that helped me sort it out. You pointed out several things wrong with my tests, which I fixed, but I think the specific error was that I wasn't creating the association and I was able to do that by setting the speaker and topic as names of other artist fixtures. Once I cleaned that up the tests passed.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly Great! :)